# Setting http option as 'responseType: 'text'' causes compile failure for a http post request with angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular9

Although there is an overloaded API method in angular HttpClient as bellow:

```
 post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'text';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<string>;
```

when I try to do bellow post request with the option 'responseType: 'text'' I get a compiler error stating "No overload matches this call. ..."

```
const opts = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
      }),
      responseType: 'text'
    };
    return this.http.post<string>('url', null, opts);
```

Note : I'm passing null as response body sensibly as my API doesn't accept a body.
What I'm I doing possibly wrong here?

**Update**
Adding the full error message as per the request by Michael D

```
Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
      Property 'observe' is missing in type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' but required in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Overload 2 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
      Property 'observe' is missing in type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' but required in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "response"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Overload 3 of 15, '(url: string, body: any, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
      Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.ts(2769)
http.d.ts(2293, 9): 'observe' is declared here.
http.d.ts(2409, 9): 'observe' is declared here.
```

Comment: put ``application/text`` instead

Comment: @muasif80: No, `responseType` property is of union type `'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text'`.

Comment: I have seen you are putting `;` in your object. Not sure if its the correct way, it does not seem correct to me

Comment: @muasif80 the first code posting is actually is the post() API declaration in the angular's HttpClient and not something I've written

Comment: this seems to be an inherent problem with angular HttpClient which haven't been resolved yet.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

Comment: @Priyal85: Could you please post the entire error message in the question for the sake of reference?

Comment: Ok actually you have to put the options responseType inline in the post call. That will not give you the error. That link that you shared in the comment also talking about that. When you put it inline it infers the correct type. @Priyal85

Comment: You can check this reply and see he is explaining it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586#issuecomment-323216764

Comment: It seems like you send the json from server and try to get the string in client. Ensure that your server provide the right data type.     Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've figured out the fault in my code thanks to this comment from reppners [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586#issuecomment-332440756) 
The problems is that I'm trying to use generics type for the post() method call which is applicable only when the responseType is equal to 'json'. Have a look at the HttpClient's post method overloaded declarations bellow

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'text';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<string>;

 post<T>(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<T>;
```

Therefore bellow is the working code for my problem

```
 apiMethod(): Observable<string> {

    const options  = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
      }),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text'
  };
    return this.http.post('url', null, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the `responseType` property. Assigning it as a string like this won't work straight away.

You can either cast it as a `text` type

```
const opts  = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
  }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'text' //<== here
};

    this.http.post(....);
```

**Edit**
This will only work with using non generic version of http calls (`this.http.post(...)` but not generic versions `this.http.post<string>`)

Or, you can declare your options as `any`, this should stop the compiler from complaining

```
const opts : any = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
  }),
  responseType: 'text'
};

this.http.post<string>(....)
```

Comment: it still fails with error ```Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)```
when I cast it as string. My observable is of type 'string' if I mind you, BTW

Comment: What if you use the `any` cast?

Comment: same outcome with any cast as well.

Comment: You mean casting `opts` as any? Weird, it works for me (1st options did not work as I missed the `string` observable)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is strange behavior. The `options` in `HttpClient` are not really of any type. It is customized for each overloading.

You will have to pass the `options` as a whole into the `http` call.

```
return this.http.post<string>('url', null, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
      }),
      responseType: 'text'
    });
```

Or as David suggested set the `options` type as `any`.

Answer (score 0):

`opts['responseType']` is inferred as `string`. Try `responseType: 'text' as const` or

```js
const opts = {
   ...
} as const;
```